# event.returnValue in IE6

Tags: javascript, dom-events

The following code should not open a new window in IE and Firefox. Its not opening in Firefox, but it is opening in IE. Whats going wrong?

```
var EventLib = {
    "preventDefault"  : function(event){
        if(event.preventDefault) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }else{
            window.event.returnValue = false;
        }           
    }
}

window.onload = function(){
  var elem = document.getElementById("link");
    elem.onclick = function(e){
    EventLib.preventDefault(e);
    }
}
```

and the HTML is:

```
<a id="link" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Click</a>
```

Comment: Is it only IE6? Worked fine in IE9.

Comment: shouldn't it just be `event.returnValue = false`, not `window.event.returnValue`?

Comment: @nrabinowitz: No. No event parameter is passed to event handlers assigned via property in IE < 9. You need to use the global `window.event` object instead .

Answer (score 1):

It could be that evaluating the expression `event.preventDefault` throws an error when `event` is undefined.  Try using `if (event && event.preventDefault)` rather than just `if (event.preventDefault)`.

Answer (score -1):

Just change function as I have shown it below, it will work

```
var EventLib = {
        "preventDefault"  : function(event){
            if(!event)
                event = window.event;
            if(event.preventDefault) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }else{
                window.event.returnValue = false;
            }           
        }
    }
```